# Background location updates for iOS display GPS icon the entire time

Tags: iphone, ios, background, core-location, cllocationmanager

My app runs significant location change updates in the background.  However the GPS display icon never turns off..even when app is in the background.  Is there a way to use location manager with Significant location change in the background and have the GPS icon NOT display continuously?  My users don't understand that it is only periodically obtaining location coordinates and instead think its constantly running in background and thus deleting app thinking its too power intensive.  Please help.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue right now, great question. I haven't tried yet, but will be shortly, using the CLRegion -startMonitoringForRegion. It will add the location arrow as well, but doesn't require the callbacks for significant changes. I only need to monitor the enter/exit of the region.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that any use of CoreLocation will prompt the location arrow. That includes any of the geofencing CLRegion use, -startMonitoringForSignificantLocationChanges, and -startMonitoringForLocation. I think that is Apple's safeguard that something is using your GPS, even in limited use.

Answer (score 0):

That arrow will be visible till you unregister your application from significant change. But I faced problem, what I can't fine point where I can do this. In my case will be best to unregister on application kill, but with multitasking there is no such ability to handle this moment to unregister.